# Which protocol should I use for a networked Pong clone?

Tags: networking, server, mobile

I have to design a Pong game for Android. There are multiple mobiles and a game server. Application is installed in mobile. Mobile 1 (M1) can see the movement of bat and ball of mobile 2 (M2) an vice-versa.

Suppose if M1 hits the ball, all the movements of the ball and bat of M1 can be seen on M2's screen and vice-versa. Now I want to know which protocol I should use and why?

Edited:
how can a server take the initiative to send a message? What are the different methods to do this:  i.e. "push", other,...

Comment: Why more than 2 people?

Comment: Is this really just a rephrasing/clarification of your [other question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/tcp-vs-udp-on-mobile-platforms)? You should probably just edit that one if so.

Comment: @James spectators, obviously...

Comment: @Zaky Pong is a simple game, you could easily have multiple paddles and not just two.. So yeah the question is are there N number of players or 2 players with 0+ spectators or what not. Sorry I wasn't clear in asking for clarification :)

Comment: @James i see, i was just being a smartass anyway, not sure how fun it would be to spectate over a pong game :) Might be a nice practice for a programmer though...

Comment: how can there be more then 2 paddles as pong is played by 2 players at a time.I want to know which protocol should i use for this and Why..

Comment: I hope you are running this over wifi only, ping from cellular data will at least be 300-400 ms, 1000 is not uncommon and higher is possible.

Comment: hello AttackingHobo : as i am very new to this game technology and cellular data ,, so can u explain what are these numbers 300-400ms and what exactly u want to explain...

Comment: @GameBuilder that's latency, measured in milliseconds. It's how long it takes to receive acknowledgement of a sent packet. It's also known as lag.

Comment: @AttackingHobo : help me more about the latency.i tell the scenario

Comment: Suppose there are 2 mobiles having and game server.The should be designed for 3G network.Please be more specific about the different protocols http / tcpip / udp.
Estimation of latency time, different elements of protocol, logic of the
communication, setup of the communication (client role, server role).
I am looking for a solution for Android AND iPhone.

Comment: How can server send messages to mobile phones?
How about "push messages" ? Do not forget that billing (who pays the
network use?) is an important element in this discussion.
We do not need that the server initiates the communication, this can be done by the mobile (client) at start of the game.
So how about initializing a bidirectional communication channel with TCP/IP from client side? Then, during the game client and server use this channel to send to each other UDP messages?

Comment: @GameBuilder You will have to make your game lag tolerant. Pong seems like a game that will literally be impossible to place nicely at over 300 ping. You have to allow each client have a delay of .3 seconds to 3 seconds for the opponents move, meaning fast games like pong where the ball could move back and forth multiple times per second wont work at all, or in order to make them work you will have to delay the game while the opponent receives the information and reacts to it, and resends it back.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend the [User Datagram Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) -- have each client send user inputs to your server, have your server calculate the results of all inputs and respond that result to each client.

```
**Pseudo Code for UDP Client/Server**
// public
int sendSequenceID= 0;
int receiveSequenceID = 0;

// send data
var data = new { id = sendSequenceID, DeltaX = changeInXCoord, DeltaY = changeinYCoord };
udpSocket.Send(data);
sendSequenceID++;

//receive data
var receivedData = null;
udpSocket.Receive(receivedData);
if(receivedData.id > receivedSequenceID) // ignore packets out of order
{
    receivedSequenceID = receivedData.id;
    // process received data
}
```

Answer (score 4):

TCP and UDP would be the two choices for this and you will want to go with UDP.

As for the Why part of your question, TCP is a 'guaranteed delivery' system, but its slow. For video games and where up to date information is a priority over ensuring the data gets there, UDP fits the bill. You will generally want to have an incremented Packet ID so you can ignore outdated packets to take care of them showing up in the wrong order, but this will suit your needs.

EDIT: A bit more information on the incremented packet IDs. With TCP, you are not only guaranteed that the data is sent, but that it is sent in the right order. It will not try to send a new piece of data along the same TCP connection until the current one has been confirmed to be sent.

UDP does not guarantee delivery order. So if you have an incrementing ID in the packet data and you keep track of that value, you will know that incoming data with an ID lower than what you have already processed is old data. In that way you can safely ignore that packet and just wait for the next one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Tell me how http is used in mobile gaming, And is there any other protocol except TCP UDP for communication.Is there any document so that i can read How HTTP TCP UDP is related with gaming

Comment: HTTP is just an extra set of protocols over TCP. You would use it for web based games where real time isnt really a factor... even with HTML 5 and web sockets coming down the pipe though, ya may not need to use HTTP for much more than delivery of a client at the end of the day..

Comment: Hello James Plz explain increment packet Id so we can ignore outdated packets

Comment: Had to put it in the answer as it will not fit in the comment.

Comment: Hello James.. thank you very much for such a valuable comments..If you have more information how UDP is Useful and about the packet Id,plz write it on the forum or mail me pratyush.sinha2511@gmail.com

Comment: @GameBuilder see my edit for a pseudo code example of using UDP to ignore out of order packets.

Comment: @James: I need more help.I will tell u the scenario .
Suppose there are 2 mobiles having Pong game and game server.The should be designed for 3G network.Please be more specific about the different protocols http / tcpip / udp. Estimation of latency time, different elements of protocol, logic of the communication, setup of the communication (client role, server role). I am looking for a solution for Android AND iPhone.
How can server send messages to mobile phones? How about "push messages" ? Do not forget that billing (who pays the network use?)

Comment: We do not need that the server initiates the communication, this can be done by the mobile (client) at start of the game. So how about initializing a bidirectional communication channel with TCP/IP from client side? Then, during the game client and server use this channel to send to each other UDP messages?

Comment: I can not give you latency estimates over 3G network besides 'Depends on signal strength, clarity, carrier, etc'. I also can not architect a networking system for you, but here are my overall thoughts. Use TCP to connect to a server for match making. Once two clients have been put together then I would say definitely use UDP for game-play packets. Whether you want to support 3G and/or WIFI connections from the phone depends on the abilities of the targeted phones and what you want to develop. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use TCP while match making and UDP for game play packets? Plz Explain?

Comment: Matchmaking requires guaranteed communication (Find Partner, Partner Found, Begin Match, etc) which TCP can do (UDP can as well, just takes a bit more work). Any sort of real time interactive game where actions over a second matter (like the position of the ball and paddles) need to be as real time as possible, which is what UDP is good for and TCP sucks at. So TCP for where real-time to the second doesnt matter (match making) and UDP when it does (Game play).

Comment: What is Push Message and how it can be used here..

Comment: Its a notification system and it -might- be useful if you do not have too popular of a game to let someone look for a match over a long period of time and let them know when a second person has finally shown up. You will have to look at the respective APIs of your target devices to figure out how they are used however.

Comment: Is it possible that server sends the push notification to client2 that client1 wants to play with client2?

Comment: Yes, sorry. A Push Notification simply means that the server is pushing the notification to a client.. So Client 1 would tell the server it wants a game, it would have a list of people who want to be notified by Push when someone is around to play and then the server would send a notification of 'Person available' or something like that.

Comment: As u Already Mentioned that Latency depends upon signal strength clarity carrier.Suppose if all the above condition are perfectly fine. but I want to speed up the sending and receiving of game Play packets ,is there any method,or is there any thing i have to take care of??

Comment: While you do not want to delay sending packets, as you want them to send as often as they need to. Packaging multiple available updates of information together and sending them at once is the best way. it will take more time to send the position of a paddle then a ball then another paddle then it will to send all three of those pieces of information at once for instance. The smaller the size of the data to send the more small parts you can pack together and still send nice (4096byte) packets and the like.

Comment: hello James . How HTTP protocol can be used in this Game.?

Comment: Is there some reason you would want to? I can not think of any particularly useful application to do it.

Comment: This is not a forum.  If you have questions, just ask a new question.  Comments aren't for a long back and forth.

Comment: @Tetrad : Hello Moderator,I understand ,But these question are interrelated with each other as they belong to same Project.If Every time i will add a new question on different Page then every time i have to explain why i am asking this question,Where i have to use the solution.

Comment: @james:As i am playing this game on 3G network ,will the IP address of the mobile changes,as we may change our position, Base station will also change.

Comment: I am sorry man but while there may be some good information here Tetrad is correct, the original question has been answered and this is not the chat rooms. Please ask a full new question if you need more answers as no one is likely to read this far for all of the information.